# jQuery on click not performing actions as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've faced a very weird issue today. I'm using below `HTML` code for a login form and I am using below `JS` to make sure that it performs operations as expected.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.account__login-form-button', function() {
  $('form#login input').each(function() {
    if (isBlank($(this).val())) {
      proceed = false;
      toastr.error('Login credentials cannot be left blank.', 'Please Enter Login Details!', {
        closeButton: !0,
        showMethod: 'slideDown',
        hideMethod: 'slideUp',
        preventDuplicates: true,
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
      });
    } else
      proceed = true;
  });

  if (proceed) {
    var buttonText = $('.account__login-form-button').text();
    var username = $('.account__login-form-username').val();
    var password = $('.account__login-form-password').val();

    $('[class^=account__login-form-]').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login">
  <div class="form-group text-center text-success col-md-offset-4 col-md-4" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span id="create_account">
      Don't have an account? Click here to create one!
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control account__login-form-username" name="account_login" placeholder="Username / Mobile / Email-ID">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control account__login-form-password" name="account_login" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <div class="pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <span id="for-pass" name="account_login">
        Forgot password?
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <button name="account_login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary account__login-form-button">Login Now!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reasons I don't know what the click event is not being triggered, I also saw if there is an error in the console but nothing there as well.

I even tried changing the class name but same also I'm using this code `$( '[class^=account__login-form-]' ).attr( 'disabled', true );` as a direct inject from developers tool console to check if it works or not it does not work there as well. I'm working for a long time on JS but never encountered this weird issue.

Comment: Did you add debugger or console lines and see if it is being triggered? Is the button submitting the form since that is its default action?

Comment: i've used `$( document ).on( 'submit', false );` in my appController.js but the problem is why is it not taking click event. It should at least trigger if i have provided a class name

Comment: Your selector is looking for the wrong element type - `$('form#login)` should be `$('div#login')`

Comment: Also note that you set `proceed = true` ***inside*** the loop. This means that so long as the last `input` contains a value then the processing will continue, despite the previous fields being invalid. You should set `proceed = true` outside the loop only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple tiny mistakes...

1. There is no `<form>` element in your HTML. You only have a Bootstrap `.form-group` class used.
2. You should declare the `proceed` variable before the `.each()` loop.
3. After the loop, test the `proceed` value... Not inside.
4. To disable the inputs, use the `*=` (contains) operator instead of `^=` (starts with)... Because the `account__login-form-___` class is not always the first class in the class attribute.

And I changed the condition to test if an input is empty... `isBlank()` seems to be an excel function... Unless you coded it yourself.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.account__login-form-button', function() {

  // Add this here
  var proceed = true

  // There is no <form> element in your HTML.
  $('#login input').each(function() {

    if ($(this).val().trim() === "") {
      proceed = false;
      toastr.error('Login credentials cannot be left blank.', 'Please Enter Login Details!', {
        closeButton: !0,
        showMethod: 'slideDown',
        hideMethod: 'slideUp',
        preventDuplicates: true,
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
      });
    }
  });  // END each loop
  
  // AFTER the each loop, test the "proceed" value
  console.log("proceed", proceed)

    if (proceed) {
      var buttonText = $('.account__login-form-button').text();
      var username = $('.account__login-form-username').val();
      var password = $('.account__login-form-password').val();
      
      console.log(buttonText, username, password)

      $('[class*=account__login-form-]').attr('disabled', true);
      console.log("inputs are now disabled")
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.4/toastr.min.js"></script>

<div id="login">
  <div class="form-group text-center text-success col-md-offset-4 col-md-4" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span id="create_account">
                Don't have an account? Click here to create one!
            </span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control account__login-form-username" name="account_login" placeholder="Username / Mobile / Email-ID">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <input type="password" class="form-control account__login-form-password" name="account_login" placeholder="Enter Password">
    <div class="pull-right" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <span id="for-pass" name="account_login">
                    Forgot password?
                </span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
    <button name="account_login" class="btn btn-block btn-primary account__login-form-button">Login Now!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: all your points make sense. Let me check this and mark this as a correct and appropriate answer BTW `is_blank()` is a function I have created as a global in my appController.js it has a logic to check if a variable is null or '' or string length < 0

Comment: Worked like charm bro